# Vapor not rendering file through Leaf

Tags: swift, vapor, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am trying to add a Skeleton-templated view to a recent Vapor 2 app that, so far, only produces JSON output with a MySQL database. If I use the following minimal code:

```
    get("viewTest")
    { req in
        let params = try Node(node: [ "name": "nick"])
        return try self.view.make("index",Node(node:params))
    }
```

The file `index.leaf` exists in the `Resources/Views` folder and the documentation suggests that omitting the `.leaf` suffix is fine, but doing so gets:

```
[Data File Error: unable to load file at path /Users/test/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Apps/Vapor/testServer/Resources/Views/index]
```

However, if I put the suffix in explicitly, `self.view.make("index.leaf",Node(node:params))`, the contents of the file are output without being rendered:

```
    #extend("base") #export("body") {#(name)}
```

I have tried putting the code directly into Main.swift and that makes no difference and putting it into a handler. I've also tried creating a new Vapor 2 project from scratch (using a fresh install of vapor) and it behaves the same. It seems odd that something so fundamental doesn't work out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that although the default renderer for Droplet is 'leaf', the default setting in Config is 'static'. Putting:

```
 "view": "leaf"
```

into `Config/drop.json` fixed the problem.

Comment: Good work. You should ‘accept’ this answer so the site knows it is solved.

Comment: Thanks @tobygriffin - I can't for another 14 hours at the time of typing.